# Plasmoid won't attach to desktop

Tags: plasmoid, kde-plasma

Trying to learn the fine art of Plasma5 (specifically 5.12) plasmoid development. I'm aspiring to be a minor KDE documentation contributor.

It's a simple plasmoid that pops open when clicked and displays a message. It runs fine inside of plasmoidviewer and "compiles" correctly with kpackagetool5. It shows up in the panel of available widgets, but I can't drag it to my desktop. I've put the (extremely simple) source up on Github; hopefully someone's willing to take a look.

https://github.com/bundito/hellomoid

Thanks a lot. I'm trying to document as I learn. But I've clearly got a lot to learn.

Answer (score 1):

After studying a few existing (and working plasmoids), I found a few differences in the `metadata.desktop` file. These differ from what's shown in the existing tutorial.

[image: metadata.desktop diff output]

The most important change appears to be the line `X-KDE-Library` entry. I removed it, and everything works. I'm not sure what it's for - I presume loading some external library - but without it, we're happy hackers again.

So there you go. I hope my discovery will help someone else.

Comment: Yes, you DID help me! I wrote my first plasmoid and followed the tutorial and had the same issue. After removing these two lines, it worked - thanks! :-)